# How do I create a generic method with nested T's?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I had a generic extension method

```
public static IList<T> Replace<T>(this IList<T> source, Ilist<T> newList) where T:IStateful
```

which I called using

```
myStatefulSetOfStuff = myStatefulSetOfStuff.Replace(GetNewSetOfStuff());
```

I realized, though, that my method would work on all collections that implement ICollection, so I changed it to

```
public static ICollection<T> Replace<T>(this ICollection<T> source, ICollection<T> newList) where T:IStateful
```

However, now the method returns an IColllection, which forces me to write the call as:

```
myStatefulSetOfStuff = myStatefulSetOfStuff.Replace(GetNewSetOfStuff()).ToList();
```

How can I re-write my method so that I don't need the `.ToList()` on my call?

EDIT:
There seemes to be some confusion, so I'll try to clear it up. I have a list. I want to perform an operation on that list with a new list. No problem. And I figured out how to return a List with an extension method.

But I realized, hey, the actual code in Replace() isn't specific to Lists, it can apply to any collection. So I modified Replace to return an ICollection. This then forces the calling method to look like

```
var newStuff = left.Replace(right).ToList()
```

or

```
var newStuff = left.Replace(right).ToArray()
```

etc.

But I don't want to say ToList, ToArray, etc., I want the method to just infer the correct return type from the source object. So I can say

```
var newStuff = left.Replace(right);
```

and newStuff will be of the same type as left. Right will be of the same type as well.

Comment: What type is myStatefulSetOfStuff?

Comment: Do `source` and `newList` have to be the same type? Or can they be separate types so long as both types implement `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: source and newList will be of the same type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following

```
public static TCollection Replace<TCollection, TItem>(
  this TCollection source,   
  TCollection newList)
    where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>
    where TItem : IStateful
```

Here's a use case example

```
interface IStateful { }
class Foo : IStateful { }
static void Test()
{
    ICollection<Foo> left = null, right= null;
    left.Replace<ICollection<Foo>, Foo>(right);
}
```

Unfortunately the generic parameters do appear necessary in this scenario (can't get type inference to work for this specific scenario)

**EDIT**

My answer is based off of a bit of a misread of the question.  I thought the intent was to flow the type of the `source` to the return type of the method.  Upon further re-reading though it appears you want instead to flow any source and return an `List` in all cases.  In which case I suggest you take a look at Reed's answer.

Comment: +1: This will work, and it's what was asked, but it only works if the input is a list - not sure if that's what the OP really wants to do.

Comment: @Reed can you clarify?  I've got this working with only `ICollection<T>` types.  Granted the type inference is failing for some reason but I can make it work by specifying the types explicitly

Comment: @JaredPar: You couldn't use a `List<T>` for the return type and source, but a different `ICollection<T>` for the "newList" argument, for example.  Not sure if that's what's required, but it sounded like, from the question, he wanted ICollection inputs but `IList<T>` results.

Comment: @Reed I see the point you're making now.  Had to re-read the question a few times.

Comment: @JaredPar: Yeah - not sure exactly what's wanted here, though - I had considered this, but it would still potentially require the `.ToList()`, depending on the input types, which was part of the original issue.

Comment: In this case, the original source, the new collection and the returned type should all be of the same type. I'm trying to remove .ToList() and infer the return type from the original source.

Comment: What does the calling code look like. I tried both var mergedList = oldFoos.Replace(newFoos); var margedList = oldFoos.Replace2<List<IStateful>, IStateful>(newFoos);
and neither work.

Comment: @John, added a use case example

Comment: @JaredPar, in the case that I'm describing, left already exists as IList<T>.

Comment: Actually, I think this code works, but I'm still verifying. Thanks.

Comment: OK, it does work, I just needed to get the client code right. It's myStatefulSetOfStuff = myStatefulSetOfStuff.Replace<IList<IStateful>, IStateful>(GetNewSetOfStuff());

Answer (score 3):

If you need it to always return `IList<T>,` just change it to:

```
public static IList<T> Replace<T>(this ICollection<T> source, ICollection<T> newList) where T:IStateful
```

And put the `.ToList()` call inside your extension method (unless it's already creating a list internally).

That being said, you can "nest" this by having two type parameters, if you wish to do so.